# Get row of df1 if column value not in column df2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Set-up**

I have 2 pandas DataFrames,

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 3], 'col2' : [10, 11, 12], 'col3' : [4, 5, 6]}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = {'col1' : [1, 2, 4], 'col2' : [10, 11, 12]})
```

such that `df1` is,

```
   col1  col2  col3
0     1    10     4
1     2    11     5
2     3    12     6
```

and `df2` is,

```
   col1  col2
0     1    10
1     2    11
2     4    12
```

---

**Issue**

I want to select all rows in `df2` that have a value in `col1` which is not in `col1` in df2.

In the example, that means `result_df` should be,

```
   col1  col2
2     4    12
```

but the following try,

```
result_df = df2[~df2.col1.isin(list(df2['col1']))]
```

results in an empty dataframe.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `df2[~df2.col1.isin(df1['col1'])]`, note that you're not using `df1` at any point

Comment: the iterable from a df are the column names you want this: `result_df = df2[~df2.col1.isin(df1['col1'])]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove list([`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) working with `Series` nice) and change `df2` to `df1`:

```
result_df = df2[~df2['col1'].isin(df1['col1'])]
print (result_df)
   col1  col2
2     4    12
```